# knockout.js 2.1 and multiple select binding bug

Tags: knockout.js

Im not sure if this is a bug or not but knockout.js 2.1 doesn't work with this sample when 1.2.1 does.
http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/kKNtv/

Update the external resource to use 2.1 and it stops working:
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js

```
dataList = [ {name:'length1',id:1},
             {name:'length2',id:2},
             {name:'length3',id:3},
             {name:'length4',id:4},
             {name:'length5',id:5} ]


var editOfferViewModel = { 
    selectedLength: ko.observable(),
    multiSelectedLength: ko.observableArray()    
}; 

ko.applyBindings(editOfferViewModel); 

$(document).ready(function() {
    editOfferViewModel.selectedLength(2);
    editOfferViewModel.multiSelectedLength(['2','3']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's binding to the id value, which is an integer, but you're telling it strings.  Maybe this behavior changed between knockout 1 and 2.  If you either set the selected values to integers or make the id property strings it will work.  Here's a simple example just showing the JSON of all the selected items, you can see it contains strings and the select box doesn't show anything, then when you select items they show as integers ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czJar/2/)).  Either of these two changes will work:

```
dataList = [ {name:'length1',id:1},{name:'length2',id:2},{name:'length3',id:3},{name:'length4',id:4},{name:'length5',id:5} ]
// dataList = [ {name:'length1',id:'1'},{name:'length2',id:'2'},{name:'length3',id:'3'},{name:'length4',id:'4'},{name:'length5',id:'5'} ] // this would work
...
editOfferViewModel.multiSelectedLength(['2','3']);
// editOfferViewModel.multiSelectedLength([2,3]); // this works
```

My question would be why this works at all...

1. dataList isn't part of your view model, does ko search all window properties for bindings too?  I didn't know that, but you can see it display the 'innerWidth' from the window object
2. The [selectedOptions] binding is supposed to now bind to actual javascript objects, but I guess if you specify the optionsValue parameter that is what it uses.  That's not explained well in their [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html).  I'm guessing support for this is what broke the string/integer mismatch working.